# Using href tag in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. In my content file I have the line:

```
<a href="products/myproduct">
```

I have a view file named `Myproduct.aspx` and inside the `ProductsController` there is the method:

```
   public ActionResult Myproduct()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

However for the line `<a href="products/myproduct">` Everything works fine but I get a warning saying the path `products/myproduct` does not exist. Am I doing something wrong ? Is this the right way to achieve this ?

Comment: Does it work if you use a .cshtml file instead if a .aspx one?

Comment: What is the warning you get? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your link like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Go to product", "Myproduct", "Products") %>
```

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) the first parameter is the `linkText`, second is the `actionName` and third is the `controllerName`.

This way you don't need to write the `<a href="">`on your own. If you want to write this on your own (but it's not recommended), you need to use the [`Url.Action()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Myproduct","Products") %>">Go to product</a>
```

Comment: What is the aspx way to do it ?

Comment: @Cemre you need to add `<%=` and `%>`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I do `<a href="<%= Html.ActionLink("Go to product", "Myproduct", "Products") %>"> but it does not work for some reason. The link output becomes `<a%20href=` and I get a potentially dangerous link error. Maybe I am using it wrong ?

Comment: @Cemre you don't need to add the `<a href="">`, this will be automatically rendered. If you wan't to add the a-tag on your own, then you must to to use `Url.Action()` instead. I've also added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [`Url` helpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper_methods%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) instead:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyProduct","Products")">
```